# How can i use a geoaxes to plot some geography data when a uitree callback is triggered?

Tags: matlab, object, callback, share, handle

I am developing an app programmatically, where there are a few uicomponents such as geoaxes, uitreecheckedbox and so on. I want to geoplot some data on geoaxes when uitreecheckedbox callback is triggered, but it issues an error when I assign geoaxes as "parent' object to callback function of uitreecheckedbox. How can i get geoaxes handle and use it for uitreecheckedbox callback or another app components?

I expected to all uicomponents be valid and known for other ones.